# Difference between 'far', far off' and 'far out'?

Tags: prepositions

I am a native Spanish speaker and this is getting me really frustrated.

Online dictionaries all give the same meaning for all these far + prep expressions, all say the same thing "a great distance" basically, but no disambiguation is given. It is really frustrating to encounter these situations where no disambiguation is provided so I come here asking for help from native English speakers.

What is the difference in meaning among all these expressions with far?

Comment: Please mention the dictionary you've checked.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because dictionaries *do* give different and more nuanced meanings for "far off" and "far out". The OP should edit their question and cite which dictionary they looked at.

Comment: That's not true and this is why I am asking because dictionaries don't disambiguate.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, *far* means *a long distance.*

> It it far to where we are going?

*Far off* and *far away* describe something a long distance from the speaker, or the person from whose viewpoint the sentence is written.

> He recognised his son when he was still far off.

*Far out* (apart from the slang meaning mentioned by @di's) describes something a long distance away on water (far out at sea), in space, or outside a populated area (far out in the wilderness).

Answer (score -1):

"Far" on its own is about distance.

> That cow is **far**.

"Far off" just means very far, but can be used with "not" at the beginning to say that something is close.

> That cow is **far off**.

> The restaurant is not **far off**.

"Far out" is slang for "impressive" or "wow", or another interjection.

> Did you see that massive cow?

> **Far out**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In which dialects of English is "far" idiomatic as a predicative adjective, as in "That cow is far"? IME "far away" is far more idiomatic. Yes, "far" can be used as an [adjective](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/far#Adjective) but it's generally used either attributively before the noun, or with a complement (far off, far away, far from here), or both.